# Symlink to a directory including the trailing slash and without

Tags: unix, symbolic-link

Is there any noticeable difference between symlinking to a directory including the trailing slash and doing it without, i.e. the difference in doing `ln -s somedir/ dir` vs. `ln -s somedir dir` whereby `somedir` is a directory?

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all. However, if you delete a symlink - be sure to not include the slash.

In the future, please be sure to research topics before aslking. If you had, you'd see numerous answers to this. [Example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file)